# Can declarativeNetRequest update rules before a request is sent?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension that automatically updates the search query section of the URL for search engine requests.

I would like my extension to read search engine requests using `onBeforeRequest` and create a new URL with my updates. That new URL should then become a dynamic rule which is followed by the browser.

However, `declarativeNetRequest`'s `updateDynamicRules` doesn't update the rule fast enough to redirect the request.

How can I either speed up the dynamic rule, or slow down the request?

Comment: There's no way, so you'll have either to find a different approach or abandon Chrome ManifestV3 platform altogether.

Comment: @wOxxOm So Manifest V3 compromises the capability to do something as simple as this?

Comment: Yes, it's a complete disaster, and the worst part of it is that Chromium/Google has been ignoring 99% of negative feedback for the past three years.